# Restrict health metrics by branches in a multi branch pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

In a multibranch Jenkins job, you can decide to show health metrics and they are obtained from the branch with the worse health. This is fine, except that it is common to have feature branches that fail and thus bring a poor general status to the project. Is it possible to restrict the health metrics to consider only the master and development branches?

Comment: Sadly, probably not anytime soon: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34502

Answer (score 3):

You can try to change the `healthMetrics` node over a [configure block](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob-configure):

```
configure { node ->
  node.remove(node.get('healthMetrics'))
  node / 'healthMetrics' << 'jenkins.branch.PrimaryBranchHealthMetric' {}
}
```

---

My approach was to change the health metric manually via the Web UI and compare the resulting XML of the job by appending `config.xml` to my job's URL like so: `https://jenkins.example.com/job/my-folder/job/my-multibranch-pipeline-job/config.xml`.

This [Jenkins Job DSL Playground](https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) lets you easily try out the configure block.